# Why make router private?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

In the Angular 2+ (4) [routing tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5), it shows to make the `router` a private member, e.g:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router, // <- router is private
    private heroService: HeroService) { }
    ...
) {}
```

But it doesn't provide any explanation as to *why* router is private here. Having it private makes it harder to test, so what is the reason for it being private? Is it just best-practice, or is there some security implication of having it public?

Also, specifically, how to test routing, that the right routes are navigated to in different circumstances? The tutorial does not mention testing router/routes *at all*?

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand what marking it private does, just curious as to the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `private`, `public`, or `protected` implicitly adds a class-level field where the passed constructor parameter is assigned to.

This is a TypeScript feature for less boilerplate.

You can now access the passed value using

```
someMethod() {
  this.router...
}
```

instead of

```
class MyComponent {
  router:Router;

  constructor(
    router: Router, // <- router is private
    private heroService: HeroService) { }
    ...
  ) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.router...
  }
}
```

If there is no specific reason to make it `public` or `protected`, `private` is the right option. This is what they did.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation. Make your fields **private** and functionality **public**. The client which uses your `class in this case`, need to know only what it can do, not how it do.

There are 3 access levels in TypeScript, `public, private, protected`. These keywords are supported only in Typescript level.

If you make your `variable/function` **private**, it will **not be visible** outside the class.

If you make your `variable/function` **public**, it will **be visible** outside the class.

If you make your `variable/function` **protected**, it will **be visible** only in the class itself and any class which inherits that class.

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly particular to the router in this specific example… in OOP in general, the question is always *"is this supposed to be accessed by outside code as part of the public interface of this class?"* Are you ever expecting `router` here to be exposed and accessed from anywhere else like `ctrl.router`? If not, then it's only prudent to keep it `private`. Limiting the exposed public interface to only the really necessary parts makes it easier to figure out what uses what, and refactor it later as necessary since no external code is bound to it.